# Node JS: Update Redis TTL

Tags: node.js, session, redis, node-redis

I hope that I can update Redis's TTL when the user is still active so that the user won't auto logout after 15 mints

Below is my code to save the user session

```
const session = require('express-session');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const redis = require("redis");
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'MY_SECRET',
    store: new redisStore({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 6379,
        client: client,
        ttl: 900
    }),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
          secure: true,
          maxAge: 1500
    } 
}));
```

My question is, how do I extend the TTL when the user is still active in my website?

Answer (score 1):

`resave: true` means that the socket will resave (and reset the TTL) every time the user hits the API. See [express-session docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#resave).